# Nested list comprehension problem on pandas groupby

Tags: pandas-groupby, astronomy, nested-for-loop

I have an astronomical dataset of around a few million lines and this is how it looks,

```
                     oid               mjd               mag               magerr                     ra                    dec
    0        1809105320673280.0  58338.42578125  20.6175079345703125  0.1499880552291870   12.0123176574707031  56.8318214416503906
    1        1809105320673280.0  58365.42968750  20.7830238342285156  0.1610205173492432   12.0121049880981445  56.8318862915039062
    2        1809105320673280.0  58377.37500000  20.7814407348632812  0.1609148979187012   12.0120792388916016  56.8319053649902344
    3        1809105320673280.0  58389.36328125  20.6266822814941406  0.1505994796752930   12.0119419097900391  56.8318405151367188
    4        1809105320673280.0  58430.28906250  20.7284736633300781  0.1573843955993652   12.0120868682861328  56.8317718505859375
    ...                     ...             ...                  ...                 ...                   ...                  ...
    8474460   381208110301184.0  58711.27343750  19.1085929870605469  0.0534130744636059  257.3913269042968750 -10.2478170394897461
    8474461   381208110301184.0  58723.13671875  19.4006576538085938  0.0655696913599968  257.3913879394531250 -10.2481222152709961
    8474462   381208110301184.0  58726.13281250  19.4201564788818359  0.0664852634072304  257.3913574218750000 -10.2475624084472656
    8474463   381208110301184.0  58737.16796875  19.3793220520019531  0.0645836368203163  257.3914184570312500 -10.2481050491333008
    8474464   381208110301184.0  58765.10937500  19.3963356018066406  0.0653686374425888  257.3912658691406250 -10.2478036880493164
```

I need to separate it into individual source files. First I grouped data according to observation IDs (oid). Then, I use min ra & dec in different groups to calculate the angular distance;

PyAstronomy.pyasl.getAngDist(ra1,dec1,ra2,dec2))

ra1 and dec1 belong to a group while ra2 and dec2 belong to another group. If the angular distance is smaller than a value, the code writes them into the same file.

The code is;

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
from PyAstronomy import pyasl


def data():
    cols = ['oid', 'mjd', 'mag', 'magerr', 'ra', 'dec']
    threshold = 1.5 / 3600
    df = pd.read_hdf('ztf_dr3.txt',dtype={'8':np.float32, '9':np.float32})
    pd.set_option('display.precision', 16)
    # data = data.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
    df.columns = cols
    edf = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
    grouped = df.groupby(['oid'])
    for name, i in grouped:
        edf = edf.append(i, ignore_index=True)
        for name, j in grouped:
            ang_dist = pyasl.getAngDist(i['ra'].min(), i['dec'].min(), j['ra'].min(), j['dec'].min())
            if (ang_dist <= threshold):
                edf = edf.append(j, ignore_index=True)
        edf.to_csv('result/' + str(i['oid'].min()) + '.txt', columns=cols, header=True, index=False)
        edf = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
```

It works without a problem, however, it is very slow. I tried to write it into comprehensive form,

```py
def data():
    pd.set_option('display.precision', 16)
    grouped = pd.read_hdf('ztf_dr3.txt',dtype={'8':np.float32, '9':np.float32}).groupby(['0'])
    edf = pd.DataFrame([[i, j]
                        for name, i in grouped for name, j in grouped
                        if
                        (pyasl.getAngDist(i['8'].min(), i['9'].min(), j['8'].min(), j['9'].min()) <= 1.5 / 3600.0)
                        ])
    return edf.to_csv('result/{}.txt'.format("edf['0'].min()"))
```

The problem is that the nested comprehensive list uses an enormous amount of memory (x3).

I would appreciate any idea on how I would write this code in a nested comprehensive form.

Example data file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1naJFXLJOjsQ2nVnGFX5WWH-hBdxikGq3/view?usp=sharing

EDIT: It doesn't have to be in nested comprehensive list form, I just wanted to make it faster.

Comment: No, not at all. Original code takes ~700 days, anything around a week or a month is fine for me.

Comment: Are you aware that storing observation IDs like `1809105300020528.8` as `np.float32` reduces precision and conflates originally different oids into the same group, so that the 114568 different observations in the Example data file yield just 26761 groups, and the result filenames don't match the original oids?

Comment: I presume the ~700 days are an extrapolation - how did you get this number? On my several years old Ryzen 5 1600 the first 679 output files were written in about two and a half hours, so 26761 files should take about four days. Did you estimate for more input or output files?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that the whole data is about 9.5GB .txt files (or 4.8 GB .hdf5 file), I added just a small sample. For the number, I made an educated guess. It produces ~700 files per day and I need to have around 500,000 files. I will upload the whole data today and edit the link.

Comment: I think it's not necessary to upload the whole data; I just wanted to get an idea where the different estimates come from. Far more important is the answer to my previous question about the merge of observations due to reduced precision - is this wanted?

Comment: Only to make it clear - so the real data frame on which the code is running has 10-20 times more rows than the 8474465 mentioned here?

Comment: Yes, real data has around 130million rows. For the previous question, yes this is wanted. There were 5 different observation files (I merged them) and I need to find & separate the data that belongs to the same star in different observations based on their angular distances.

Comment: Also, I saw that observation ID problem yesterday then I only converted the last two columns into `np.float32` as

`dtype={'8':np.float32, '9':np.float32}`

Comment: Q1. Could different oids in one of the 5 original files belong to the same star? - Q2. The output of the present algorithm is a multiple of the input, since each observation goes into its own file plus into each file of nearby observations. Is this absolutely required, or would a clustering algorithm which yields non-overlapping groups of observations also do?

Comment: A1. Yes, there are some stars in that data, observed at different times, so I need to merge these observations data. "If" condition is the filter that finds them. A2. Yes, it is required. There should be no non-overlapping groups since each group has to match with itself, then the second for loop will write that data into `edf`, the empty dataframe. Btw, in the original code, `edf = edf.append(i, ignore_index=True)` in the  first loop is unnecessary (just found it).

Comment: Did you get the _~700 files per day_ with `float32` oids, or with `float64`? If the former, I guess `float64` will be (due to the greater number of different observations) about 20 times as slow.

Comment: Anyway, since the full output as described is required, and you need a speedup at least from about two years to one month, I don't see enough potential for optimization to achieve this factor 24 just by tuning the code. (In fact, the only thing I can think of is to spare the many times repeated computations of `['ra'].min()` and `['dec'].min()` by computing and storing them once per group.) So, the only way may be to divide the data in (perhaps overlapping) sectors, process the sectors on several dozens of CPUs or computers, and merge the results.

Comment: I got it with float32. Well, thanks for the effort.